# how to convert text file to parquet with java spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, parquet

I'm trying to convert a text file into a parquet file. I can only find "how to convert to parquet" from other file format or code written in scala/python.
Here is what I came up with

```
import org.apache.parquet.schema.MessageType;
import org.apache.parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.*;

private static final StructField[] fields = new StructField[]{
            new StructField("timeCreate", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("cookieCreate", DataTypes.StringType, false,Metadata.empty())
};//simplified
private static final StructType schema = new StructType(fields);

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder().master("spark://levanhuong:7077")
            .appName("Convert text file to Parquet")
            .getOrCreate();
    spark.conf().set("spark.executor.memory", "1G");
    WriteParquet(spark, args);

}
public static void WriteParquet(SparkSession spark, String[] args){
    JavaRDD<String> data = spark.read().textFile(args[0]).toJavaRDD();
    JavaRDD<Row> output = data.map((Function<String, Row>) s -> {
        DataModel model = new DataModel(s);
        return RowFactory.create(model);
    });

    Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(output.rdd(),schema);
    df.printSchema();
    df.show(2);
    df.write().parquet(args[1]);
}
```

`args[0]` is a path to input file, `args[1]` is a path to the output file. here is the simplified DataModel. `DateTime` fields are properly formated in set() function

```
public class DataModel implements Serializable {
DateTime timeCreate;
DateTime cookieCreate;

public DataModel(String data){
    String model[] = data.split("\t");
    setTimeCreate(model[0]);
    setCookieCreate(model[1]);
}
```

And here is the error. Error log point to `df.show(2)` but i think the error was caused by `map()`. I'm not sure why since I don't see any casting in the code

```
    >java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of

 java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1.fun$1 
    of type org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function in instance 

    of org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1
```

I think this is enough to recreate the error, please tell me if I need to provide any more information.

Comment: You can use `spark.read.csv` for your data, just set delimiter "\t" to read tsv format.

Comment: @Hitobat thanks, this got me a bit further. i can show() but when i write it throw this error 
    "NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/parquet/hadoop/metadata/CompressionCodecName"

Comment: idk why but submitting in terminal instead of running in IntelliJ sovled this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit other approach can be used, working fine:

```
    JavaRDD<String> data = spark().read().textFile(args[0]).toJavaRDD();
    JavaRDD<DataModel> output = data.map(s -> {
        String[] parts = s.split("\t");
        return new DataModel(parts[0], parts[1]);
    });
    Dataset<Row> result = spark().createDataFrame(output, DataModel.class);
```

Class "DataModel" is better looks as simple TO, without functionality:

```
public class DataModel implements Serializable {
private final String timeCreate;
private final String cookieCreate;

public DataModel(String timeCreate, String cookieCreate) {
    this.timeCreate = timeCreate;
    this.cookieCreate = cookieCreate;
}

public String getTimeCreate() {
    return timeCreate;
}

public String getCookieCreate() {
    return cookieCreate;
}
```

}

Comment: i used your code for a test run and it still not working, also () in spark() is wrong syntax. The code inside map() was not reached so i don't think that matter. Maybe it's something with the library? i updated the imported class, can you check if there are any difference?

Comment: yes, parentheses after "spark" are not required in yours case. Code inside "map" will be reached if call action, for example "df.show(2);" as last statement in my code.

Comment: Yes, i know map() will be called by other action, but when i tried to add breakpoint or print() inside map(), none of them are reached(or this is normal?). And since the code are identical, the last thing i can think of is library

Comment: Print from "map" will be visible in executors logs, not on driver node. For check is mapper works or not, just print "result.count()". If value is not zero, mapper works fine.